# I cannot understand formula for exogenous options in statsmodels' ARIMA

Tags: regression, time-series, arima, statsmodels

I need to use exogenous variables for my time series forecasting.

And I found that I can include my exogenous variables into my ARIMA model using exogenous option.

I want to know how this option works.

Statsmodels docoument(https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.html) says

"
If exogenous variables are given, then the model that is fit is

$ϕ(L)(y_t−X_tβ)=θ(L)ϵ_t$

where ϕ and θ are polynomials in the lag operator, L. This is the regression model with ARMA errors, or ARMAX model. "

I cannot understand what this formula means.

I googled it and found what lag operator is.

But I still don't understand what the above formula implies.

I'm a undergraduate and took regression course.

Could you explain above formula in terms of regression?

Comment: Hi: can you get a hold of andew harvey's "econometric analysis of time series". if so, he gives the econometric perspective on arima models with exogenous variables which I think is quite enlightening. note that it's not an easy book but worth the effort.

Comment: Note that the statsmodel documentation calls this both "regression model with ARMA errors" and "ARMAX model". These are different models, and as described here this is a regression with ARMA errors, as explained below in the answer by @CloseToC. The line about ARMAX is an error in the statsmodel documentation.

Comment: $$\phi(L) y_t =  \phi(L) X_t \beta + \theta(L) \epsilon_t$$ I thought ARMAX refers to any ARMA model with exogenous variables, e.g.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model#ARMAX

Comment: That's also what I thought. Also: Hyndman says (https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/) there is little between the two variants of ARMA + X in terms of forecasting, but regression with ARMA error as implemented in statsmodels has a much better interpretation

Comment: @CloseToC That's correct. The fact that the interpretation (and parameters) is different is precisely why calling it "an ARMAX model" is an error in the documentation. I mentioned it because if the OP decided that they wanted to get more information about "what the formula means" and looked up "ARMAX model", they would get a completely different and incorrect answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ARMA(p,q) model has $p$ lags of the dependent variable and an error term that is a moving average of $q$ lags. In standard regression notation the model is:

$$y_t = \phi_1 y_{t-1} + ... + \phi_p y_{t-p} + \epsilon_t - \theta_1 \epsilon_{t-1} -...-\theta_q \epsilon_{t-q}$$

With the backshift/lag operator $L$ notation, you can write eg $y_{t-2}$ as as $L(L(y_t)) = L^2 y_{t} $and so you can write the model as
$$(1 - \phi_1 L - .... - \phi_p L^p) y_t = (1 - \theta_1 L - ... - \theta_q L^q)\epsilon_t$$. You can make this more compact by replacing the polynomials of the lag operator: 
$$\phi(L) y_t = \theta(L) \epsilon_t$$

So what is $$\phi(L) (y_t - X_t \beta) = \theta(L) \epsilon_t$$?

It's $$y_t - X_t \beta  - \phi_1 (y_{t-1} - X_{t-1}\beta)  - ... - \phi_p (y_{t-p} - X_{t-p}\beta) = \epsilon_t - \theta_1 \epsilon_{t-1} -...-\theta_q \epsilon_{t-q}$$
or
$$y_t =  X_t \beta  + \phi_1 (y_{t-1} - X_{t-1}\beta)  + ... +\phi_p (y_{t-p} - X_{t-p}\beta) + \epsilon_t - \theta_1 \epsilon_{t-1} -...-\theta_q \epsilon_{t-q}$$

Finally, if you define the regression residual as $u_t = y_t - X_t \beta$ you can write this as in an easy to interpret way as:

$$y_t =  X_t \beta  + \phi_1 u_t  + ... +\phi_p u_{t-p} + \epsilon_t - \theta_1 \epsilon_{t-1} -...-\theta_q \epsilon_{t-q} = X_t \beta + n_t$$

And that's simply regression with an ARMA error $n_t$ as the statsmodel documentation says.